# Error testing thrown exceptions in Spock unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

When I try to test for a thrown exception using the following code:

```
@TestFor(EncryptionService)
class EncryptionServiceSpec extends Specification {
def "test decryption of unecnrypted file"(){
    setup: 
        def clearTextFile = new File("test/resources/clearText.txt")
        clearTextFile.write("THIS IS CLEAR TEXT")

    when:
        def (privateKey,publicCert) = service.generateKeyPair("123")
        service.decryptFile(new FileInputStream(clearTextFile), privateKey )

    then:
        clearTextFile.delete()
        thrown GeneralSecurityException
}
}
```

I get the following compilation exception when I run either grails test-app -unit

> Unexpected error during compilation of spec 'com.genospace.services.EncryptionServiceSpec'. Maybe you have used invalid Spock syntax? Anyway, please file a bug report at http://issues.spockframework.org.
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.DeclarationExpression.getVariableExpression(DeclarationExpression.java:103)
>       at org.spockframework.compiler.SpecRewriter.moveVariableDeclarations(SpecRewriter.java:538)

Comment: Try running `grails clean` and re-running the tests

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to help

Comment: Are you missing any imports?

Comment: Which exact Grails version are you using, and which exact Spock version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without leveraging Groovy's multi-assignment feature (`def (privateKey,publicCert) = ...`). If this solves the problem (and I think it will), please file an issue at http://issues.spockframework.org.